# What's a good Ruby on Rails CMS for Video Sharing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

I want to be able to embed a ton of videos from youtube for my video sharing website, I was wondering if you guys know a good Ruby on Rails CMS that can handle this and organize the videos neatly. I am new to Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

if it can help you here is a list of [6 originally designed CMS on Ruby on Rails](http://www.delicious.com/jlstarland/rails+cms?opennew=1). I do unfortunately not tested.